# How to make a theme hook suggestion for blocks according to region?

Tags: blocks, 8, theming

Since Drupal 8 it is not possible with **template naming conventions** to load a specific **block template according to the region** it is placed in (["Per-region block markup and per-region block templating feature removed"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2011434)). But I need to have different html for blocks if placed in a certain region. How do I accomplish this?

I've thought about using *MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_block_alter* but I don't know how to get the current region.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get region if you get Block Entity.

**.module or .theme file**

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

function MODULE_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['elements']['#id'])) {
    $block = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $block->getRegion() . '__' . $variables['elements']['#id'];
  }
  /* Use this 'else if' only if you are using page_manager module and want to know which region is the block */
  else if (isset($variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__page_' . $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'] . '__' . end(explode(':', $variables['elements']['#plugin_id']));
  }
  return $suggestions;
}
```

**Edit 1:** Cover page_manager module case.

Comment: Almost perfect. You need to add an isset() to make sure that the #id is really there. For example, if you use page_manager and place blocks in there, then you won't have an #id.

Comment: @Berdir thanks ;) . I think that in this case `isset()` is not required, because if there isn't an `#id`, then it pass `NULL` to `::load` function, and just return `NULL`. In the end, `$block` is `NULL` and nothing will happen. Tested in my dev env Drupal 8.0.4 - page_manager-1.0-alpha23 (never used this module before).

Comment: Yes, isset() is required. accessing an array key that doesn't exist results in a PHP notice. Check your logs and you'll see. I would recommend to always develop with error display on verbose, which is the default of the provided example settings.php.

Comment: You don't need `return $suggestions;` at the end since that variable is passed by reference.