# Is it possible to make a theme hook suggestion for blocks according to content type?

Tags: theming, blocks

I was hoping it was possible to do something similar to this for menus:

```
 * Implementation of hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for menus.
 *  * Make menus themeable:
 * e.g. => menu--main--node-type--page.html.twig
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_menu_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'menu__'.$variables['menu_name'].'__node_type__%';
    $suggestions[] = 'menu__'.$variables['menu_name'].'__node_type__'.$content_type;
  }
}
```

But for blocks, because the main navigation block suggestions look like this for me:

```
 * block--system-menu-block--main.html.twig
 * block--system-menu-block.html.twig
 * block--system.html.twig
 * block.html.twig
```

And I was hoping that I could have something like `block--system-menu-block--main--page.html.twig`?

Answer (score 0):

After trying more solutions in different answers, modifying this one finally worked for me: [How to make a theme hook suggestion for blocks according to region?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/how-to-make-a-theme-hook-suggestion-for-blocks-according-to-region?rq=1)

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['elements']['#id'])) {
    $block = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);
    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      $content_type = $node->bundle();
      $suggestions[] = 'block__'.$variables['elements']['#id'].'__node_type__'.$content_type;
    }
  }
}
```